# How to run ch08/SumFile.hs of realworldhaskell.org?

Tags: haskell

http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/efficient-file-processing-regular-expressions-and-file-name-matching.html

I tried to run SumFile.hs with the following command. It just hangs there. Could anybody let me know how to run it?

```
$ runhaskell SumFile.hs
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you ran it successfully. The program reads from stdin until it closes, then prints a result. Until you close stdin, it's not going to produce any output. Consider redirecting a file to stdin.

```
$ runhaskell SumFile.hs < some_numbers.txt
```